# Why is the X Clipboard Storing JPG Images as Large files?

Tags: linux, x11, xfce, clipboard

I've been delving into a bizarre behavior of the X clipboard on my Linux setup.

I initially copied an image from a web browser, which I later identified to be in JPG format when I saved the file. But when I tried to paste the copied image from browser into WhatsApp, I encountered an error saying, "One image you tried adding is larger than the 16MB limit."

To diagnose this, I took the following steps:

#### Direct Image Save:

- Saved the image directly from the browser: Resulted in a 1.7MB JPG.

#### Clipboard Inspection (Initial):

- Used `xclip` to inspect the clipboard content.
- Found that the image was referenced in `text/html` format. No PNG format was initially available in the `-t TARGETS` output.

  ```bash
  $ xclip -o selection clipboard -t TARGETS
  TIMESTAMP
  TARGETS
  MULTIPLE
  text/html
  text/_moz_htmlcontext
  text/_moz_htmlinfo
  UTF8_STRING
  COMPOUND_TEXT
  TEXT
  STRING
  text/plain;charset=utf-8
  text/plain
  text/x-moz-url-priv
  ```
- Other options from targets above didn't work with error `Error: target ... not available`. Upon inspection with target as `text/html`:

  ```bash
  $ xclip -o -selection clipboard -t text/html
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"><img src="https://i.redd.it/678a4i8vv7l01.jpg" alt="Flashed Libreboot to X200 using BeagleBone Black : thinkpad" class=" nofocus" tabindex="0" aria-label="Flashed Libreboot to X200 using BeagleBone Black : thinkpad" role="button">
  ```

#### Clipboard Size:

- On further inspection, I discovered the clipboard was storing the image in PNG format, with a size exceeding 16MB.
- Disabled the internet, copied the image from Firefox browser.
- Tried to paste while offline, but now targets for `image/png` got enabled. I saved the image to a file:

  ```bash
  $ xclip -o -selection clipboard -t image/png > /ramdisk/extracted_image.png
  ```

  Now `image/png` target is enabled for all copied images.

#### Clipman Test:

- Disabled Clipman and tried copying again, but the large PNG issue when pasting to WhatsApp persisted.

#### GIMP Test:

- Copied the image in GIMP.
- `xclip` now showed PNG-related targets.

#### Image Extraction:

- Extracted the image from the clipboard: Resulted in an 18.1MB PNG.

  ```bash
  $ \ls -l /ramdisk/extracted_image.png 
  -rw-r--r-- 1 sourav sourav 18134833 Aug 16 19:44 /ramdisk/extracted_image.png
  ```
- Clipman's cached version was a slightly smaller 16MB PNG.

  ```bash
  $ \ls -l ~/.cache/xfce4/clipman/image0.png 
  -rw-r--r-- 1 sourav sourav 600951 Aug 16 20:55 /home/sourav/.cache/xfce4/clipman/image0.png
  ```

#### Compression Check:

- Ran `pngcheck` on both images.

  ```bash
  $ pngcheck /home/sourav/.cache/xfce4/clipman/image0.
  OK: /home/sourav/.cache/xfce4/clipman/image0.png (4896x3264, 32-bit RGB+alpha, non-interlaced, 74.8%).
  ```

  ```bash
  $ pngcheck /ramdisk/extracted_image.png
  OK: /ramdisk/extracted_image.png (4896x3264, 32-bit RGB+alpha, non-interlaced, 71.6%).
  ```

#### Exiftool Check:

- Ran `exiftool` on both images.

  ```bash
  $ exiftool /ramdisk/extracted_image.png /home/sourav/.cache/xfce4/clipman/image0.png
  ======== /ramdisk/extracted_image.png
  ExifTool Version Number         : 12.60
  File Name                       : extracted_image.png
  Directory                       : /ramdisk
  File Size                       : 18 MB
  File Modification Date/Time     : 2023:08:16 19:44:02+05:30
  File Access Date/Time           : 2023:08:16 19:43:59+05:30
  File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2023:08:16 19:44:02+05:30
  File Permissions                : -rw-r--r--
  File Type                       : PNG
  File Type Extension             : png
  MIME Type                       : image/png
  Image Width                     : 4896
  Image Height                    : 3264
  Bit Depth                       : 8
  Color Type                      : RGB with Alpha
  Compression                     : Deflate/Inflate
  Filter                          : Adaptive
  Interlace                       : Noninterlaced
  Significant Bits                : 8 8 8 8
  Image Size                      : 4896x3264
  Megapixels                      : 16.0
  ======== /home/sourav/.cache/xfce4/clipman/image0.png
  ExifTool Version Number         : 12.60
  File Name                       : image0.png
  Directory                       : /home/sourav/.cache/xfce4/clipman
  File Size                       : 16 MB
  File Modification Date/Time     : 2023:08:16 19:50:18+05:30
  File Access Date/Time           : 2023:08:16 19:50:11+05:30
  File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2023:08:16 19:50:18+05:30
  File Permissions                : -rw-r--r--
  File Type                       : PNG
  File Type Extension             : png
  MIME Type                       : image/png
  Image Width                     : 4896
  Image Height                    : 3264
  Bit Depth                       : 8
  Color Type                      : RGB with Alpha
  Compression                     : Deflate/Inflate
  Filter                          : Adaptive
  Interlace                       : Noninterlaced
  Significant Bits                : 8 8 8 8
  Image Size                      : 4896x3264
  Megapixels                      : 16.0
      2 image files read
  ```

From the above steps, it's evident that the clipboard is storing the JPG image as a much larger PNG. This leads me to several questions:

- What's causing this conversion? Is it the browser, the X system, or another tool?
- Why was the image initially available only in `text/html` format and later downloads it as a PNG?
- What exact data is the clipboard storing that inflates the image size so significantly?